# Different format JSON deserializing to object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, websocket, json.net

I have a memory stream of data I have received from Poloniex's API.
https://docs.poloniex.com/#ticker-data

The data in the API looks in the format below:

```json
[
    1002,
    null,
    [
        149,
        "382.98901522",
        "381.99755898",
        "379.41296309",
        "-0.04312950",
        "14969820.94951828",
        "38859.58435407",
        0,
        "412.25844455",
        "364.56122072",
        0,
        0
    ]
]
```

I can see that this is valid json on https://jsonlint.com/

My end goal is I want to deserialize this into an object in C# which I can send elsewhere.

I've never seen JSON like this before and unsure how I would deserialize this structure into my own model. I'm used to see JSON as `keyvaluepairs`

I've deserialized into a JArray and going from there but I'm unsure of the best approach.

```cs
var deserialized = 
    (JArray)_serializer.Deserialize(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)) 
    { 
        CloseInput = false 
    });
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Example model structure to deserialize into:

```
public class PoloniexResponseDataRoot
    {
        public List<PoloniexResponseDataParent> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class PoloniexResponseDataParent
    {
        public int ChannelNumber { get; set; }
        public int? OtherNumber { get; set; }
        public List<PoloniexResponseDataChild> Children { get; set; }

    }

    public class PoloniexResponseDataChild
    {
        public object Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say "which I can send elsewhere.", does that mean you will post it off to another API?

Comment: Yes correct, I want to map it to this an object which I can easily automap into one of our response models. The problem is getting it from this format here into a model. I have updated my original post with a response model, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your structure is as simple as the one in your example and that the first 2 numbers always represent `ChannelNumber` and `OtherNumber` followed by 1 level array, then you can do something like this:

```cs
private static PoloniexResponseDataParent Parse(JArray objects)
{
    var parent = new PoloniexResponseDataParent();
    var channelNumber = objects[0];
    var otherNumber = objects[1];
    var children = objects[2];
    parent.ChannelNumber = Convert.ToInt32(channelNumber);
    parent.OtherNumber = (otherNumber as JValue).Value<int?>();
    parent.Children = children.Select(item => new PoloniexResponseDataChild
    {
        Data = item switch
        {
            JValue jValue => jValue.Value,
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(item))
        }
    }).ToList();
    return parent;
}



var jArray = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonStr);

var parent = Parse(jArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This JSON is basically an Array of objects.

```
List<object> items = _serializer.Deserialize<List<object>>(jsonString);
```

You could then create a new class and assign the object to the class
Or simple use it as it.

Comment: What would a class structure for this look like? The JSON doesn't have any keys just values.

Comment: You can create your own keys. Read the documentation of the api and understand what each value mean and then create a class of your own.

Comment: of which API? I have added a model stucture above